# How to find COM port for PuTTy (Mac)

Tags: macos, putty

I am doing a lab for my class using Code Composer Studio and the Tiva Launchpad. I am using a macbook and I have downloaded PuTTy using MacPorts. Now that PuTTy is running I have to type in the serial line to communicate with CCS and the Launchpad.

It is necessary to type in the serial line for connection to work,
[PuTTy Serial line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZPlr.png)

Any help or direction is very appreciated! First time posting sorry if I am unclear at any point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy way to find the device special file for any device.

Unplug the device and reboot your system.

Get a list of all device special files in `/tmp/a`

```
ls /dev > /tmp/a
```

Now plug in your device and wait a few seconds, and get a list of the device special files again, this time in `/tmp/b`:

```
ls /dev > /tmp/b
```

Now compare `/tmp/a` with `/tmp/b`:

```
opendiff  /tmp/a  /tmp/b      # Yes, you could use "opendiff /tmp/[ab]"
```

Whatever is new in file `/tmp/b` corresponds to what you plugged in.